# How to worship in temples? Please explain in context of human body as temple

Tags: temple, worship

We know temples are a representation of human body. Please explain how one must approach each part of temple and worship it for ones progress. 
For eg one prostrates at the flagpost of temple because it represents male genital organ.. And just like sexual energy is the largest energy in a body.. That part has maximum energy.

Comment: The Agamas, method of worship properly for temples differ with Shiva, Vishnu, Shakti, Muruga temples!!!!!!

Comment: "We know temples are representation of human body." Really? I don't know that. Where did you get this idea? What sutras say this?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Swami ji, this is basic fact of hinduism - temples structure are based on human body structure. Agamas of each temples are based on it! It cant be opinion based answer!

Comment: Akshay, Thanks.. Do you know where I can get more information on this method of worship and science of temples.

Comment: Surprised swamiji doesn't know this.. No one is answering my questions..At least my question served a small pirpose.

Comment: @AkshayS I am going with SwamiVishwananda on this one. Merely saying basic fact isn't going to get this question far. Please cite the sources. Stating human body is a temple and temple is based on human body are 2 very different statements. If it's just symbolism, then the answer here would be primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Ambi 112 structures is the way human body is there, and same 112 structure was temple built..... Its there in Agamas......Answers cannot be opinion based but rather broad one! Even tantric yoga methods are 112 only!

Dwajasthambam has same number of blocks that you have in spine!

Comment: Kindly Use @Username to reply only then I will be notified...

Comment: @AkshayS then do cite the sources, no? Statements like Dwajasthambam representing male genitals and such cannot be considered authoritative without proper reference and that too only from accepted agamas.

Comment: @Ambi But the question doesnt ask for whether temples are reflection of human body... if you go to a proper Guru, they will teach you about these things. Second Dwajasthambam is not for male genitals, its there in all temples. For further quieries about this, visit hinduism chat room of where I will explain! Kumbaibesheka which is done in 12 years is also reflection of what is there in human body.....

Comment: @AkshayS Correct. The question already assumes that it is a fact and starts of with that assertion. Anyway, let's leave the guru perspective out of this for now. In my view, the question would be fine if it simply asks for procedures to follow while visiting temples and even then it might be opinion based. If sources cannot be cited and the only explanation is more assertions, then I don't have further interest in the topic.